# Missing First Columns and First Row in Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to read an excel file in excel, but for some reason sometime, the first column is missing and first row is missing from the data.

When I open the file in excel and save it without any changes, the files are read correctly.

Any ideas about how this might happen?

Below is the code i am using to read the file:

```
string xlConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            + "Data Source="
            + txt_InputFile.Text
            + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(xlConn))
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    // Get the name of the first worksheet:
    DataTable dbSchema = dbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    if (dbSchema == null || dbSchema.Rows.Count < 1)
    {
        //"Error: Could not determine the name of the first worksheet."
        throw new Exception(Program.lm_GetMethodLanguage(this.GetType().Name, "wp_InputFile_CloseFromNext", 5) );
    }
    string firstSheetName = dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    using (
        OleDbDataAdapter dbCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + firstSheetName + "]",
                                                            dbConnection))
    {
        using (DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet())
        {
            dbCommand.Fill(myDataSet);

            inputData = myDataSet.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting `HDR=No` in the connection string, maybe?

Comment: i tried adding "HRD=No" to the connection string, I got the following exception: "Could not find installable ISAM."

Comment: I just fixed this error by adding quotations, but the problem of missing first column and row remains

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that `GetOleDbSchemaTable()` will retrieve sheet names in alphabetical order, not the order in which they appear in Excel. Now sure if this makes a difference in your case or not.

Comment: @SidHolland this makes no difference since i got only 1 sheet in the file

Comment: My problem is not related to the sheet names, it is related to the corrupt excel file that is somehow read by excel but not my application.

Comment: Have you tried reading a simple test file to see if it makes any difference? Just something very simple with a few cells filled. That should at least narrow down the problem.

Comment: @SidHolland I tried that, it works perfectly

Comment: Strange. Then there must be something unusual about your spreadsheet. What is generating it in the first place?

Comment: The spread sheet is generated through a website from an external supplier, i guess i have to inform the supplier to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

Use this.This will retrieve all the sheets in excel sheet.

```
    private String[] GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFile)
    {
        try
        {
            excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ""yoursourcepath"+ ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
            excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            excelConnection.Open();
            dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            if (dt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                i++;
            }

            return excelSheets;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (excelConnection != null)
            {
                excelConnection.Close();
                excelConnection.Dispose();
            }
            if (dt != null)
            {
                dt.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AhmadHajou No, this will only work for 2007 and up. Also, this will only retrieve the sheet _names_, not the sheet _data_.